# Fast canvas scaling

Tags: canvas, webgl

I am trying to create an editor app, that can contain thousands od items. To draw items I use 2D WebGL. One of the important feature is scaling. Scaling is done by mouse wheel. After scale `<canvas>` should update its size accordingly. When I change `<canvas>` width and hight directly:

```
canvas.width = width * scale;
canvas.width = height * scale;
```

rerendering is really slow. When I change the size by CSS:

```
canvas.style.width = width * scale;
canvas.style.height = height * scale;
```

rerendering is much faster but the image is blurry. Is there any way to speed up rendering in the first method or to sharpen the image in second?

Comment: Try to floor the scaled width and height, so you only assign integer values to canvas.width and canvas.height. Does that help?
canvas.width = Math.floor(width * scale);
Also this here is a link to the definitve guide to canvas resizing: https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-resizing-the-canvas.html
I found this super useful!

Comment: Btw: when you change the width and height properties of the canvas directly, you are actually changing the pixel size of the image buffer to be rendered on. This results in a reallocation of video memory. When you instead scale with CSS, the size of the underlying image buffer of the canvas is not changed, its just scaled by the GPU on render, so its faster.